# Sort a ListView or a ListView.ItemTemplate by a value in a specific

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin

I trying to sort or order a ListView by a value in a specific, for example by date but I haven't anything like that, I want sort the values from an API, for example by Date, but there are Notices of type Important and No important, I did it in a Grid on the Web

[image: photo]

I have to do the same but in a ListView in Xamarin

My ListView:

```
<ListView  x:Name="ItemsListView" RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}" SeparatorVisibility="None" Style="{ StaticResource ResponsiveLandscapeMarginStyle }" ItemsSource="{ Binding Messages }">
    <ListView.RowHeight>
        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Int32" Phone="120" Tablet="160" />
    </ListView.RowHeight>

<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>

            <local:DataItemTemplate />

        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

My ViewModel:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Notice> Messages { get; set; }
    public Command LoadItemsCommand { get; set; }
    public Command LoadHighImportantItems { get; set; }

    public Notice Message { get; set; }
    public Command UpdateMessage { get; }
   
    public NoticeViewModel()
    {
        Messages = new ObservableCollection<Notice>();
        LoadItemsCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadItemsCommand());
        LoadHighImportantItems = new Command(() => ExecuteLoadHighImportantItemsCommand());
        UpdateMessage = new Command(() => ExecuteUpdateRead());
    }

    async Task ExecuteLoadItemsCommand()
    {

        if (IsBusy)
            return;
        IsBusy = true;

        try
        {
            var serviceStore = new ServiceStoreAPI();
            await serviceStore.GetItemsAsync(ServicesKey.Event,true);
            await serviceStore.GetItemsAsync(ServicesKey.EmployeeServicesRequests, true);
            await serviceStore.GetItemsAsync(ServicesKey.Raffle, true);
            new EmployeeServicesRequestsViewModel().LoadItemsCommand.Execute(null);
            new RaffleViewModel().LoadItemsCommand.Execute(null);
            Messages.Clear();
            var items = await NoticeStore.GetItemsAsync(true);

            foreach (var item in items)
                Messages.Add(item);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to sort by date or by any value, to display the values in the ListView?

Comment: the ListView will sort however ItemsSource is sorted.  You can just use LINQ to sort your data however you want when you assign ItemSource

Comment: @Jason yeah, I tried something like that 
  `private ObservableCollection<Message> _messages;
   public ObservableCollection<Message> Messages
   {
        get => _messages.OrderBy(m => m.Date);
        set { _messages = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }`

But it works when I set the values in the foreach

Comment: `ItemsListView.ItemsSource = Messages.OrderBy(m => m.Date);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this

```
foreach (var item in items.OrderByDescending(d => d.Date)
  Messages.Add(item);
```

Comment: is this an answer to your question or just additional information?  If the latter, please do NOT use the answer function to do this.  Edit your original question instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would us a CollectionViewSource to order output:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="SortedComboBoxItems" Source="{Binding Path=ComboBoxItems}">
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <componentModel:SortDescription PropertyName="Order" />
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```